# Cyber security controls and Cyber insurance

Tags: appsec, cyber-warfare

Is there a minimum standard set of cyber security controls for compliance to cyber security insurance claims?

Comment: The simplest answer is no. The bigger answer is that there is no single agreement as to what cyber security insurance is, even in one country, let alone globally. .